# how to make package result of maven exported not to default local repository

Tags: maven

well, for some reason, I don't want to make the package result of maven exported to default repository(.e.g ~.m2/repository), I hope an option like below could be given:

```
mvn clean pacakge -DlocalRepository=/path/to/another/localRepository
```

So, can anyone help me make it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you following the standard practice of "mvn deploy" to a shared Maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

Just define where you want your local repo in the Pom

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Configuring your Local Repository

The location of your local repository can be changed in your user configuration. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository/.

...
  /path/to/local/repo/
  ...

Note: The local repository must be an absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear. Actually I still want the default local repository exist. What I want is that when build a certain project, I want the build result exported to another repository. Cause  I don't want them overlap the corresponding ones in ${user.home}/.m2/repository.

Comment: Do you want to use this artifact with other projects? If not, just don't `install` that project. In fact, for over 95% of the times people should prefer `mvn verify` over `mvn install`.